# PHP Winter Time in Europe/Athens

Tags: php, date, timezone

in the `php.ini` I defined the timezone to `Europe/Athens`. Everything was just fine until last sunday, when the time chanegd to WINTER TIME. The time went back in 1 hour.

The problem is, that in my website - it's still like summer time, didn't go back in 1 hour... I checked it in other website and it's ok there - http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=26

To make sure, I added this line in the top of the page:

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Athens');
```

But it dind't help...

What heppent? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please also show the code where you are getting the current time.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

`date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens');`

Comment: No. didn't help - same thing

Comment: Did you try another timezones? Did it change?

Answer (score 1):

If you just set the `default time` in the `start` of your function or program the date is format in the country you want.

```
<?php
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Athens') ;    
        echo "the date is:". date("d/m/Y")."<br/>";
        echo "the time is:". date("h:i:s");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider updating your PHP time zone database.  You can find the latest version [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).

However, I checked through the database and it looks like `Europe/Athens` has been in sync with EU since 1981, which has used the Last Sunday in October since 1996.  So even if you have a very old database I can't imagine that it would be incorrect for recent dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just two little hints:

Please check if the output of following code returns your timezone:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$tz = $date->getTimezone();
echo $tz->getName();
```

Which function or language do you use to display the time on your website? Perhaps javascript? Then the time comes from the client system.